# VB.NET Import and export MSQL data between two pcs on different networks though usb flash drive

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, merge

i've already been using Linked-servers to merge data between 2 sql servers on the same network. Right now, the other pc has no access to the network nor the internet.i need to be able to transfer and merge data in a way similar to the one i did using linked server on a usb flash drive.

any help?

Answer (score 1):

If the USB has a MDF file on it you could connect to it and use the same merge code in your other project.

Comment: Or create a backup of the database(s) in question and restore those to a different database name on that isolated server.